# Tag elimination: [problem]

Tags: feature-request, tag-block-request

I believe the tag [problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/problem) is useless as it gives no help to the question. True, it could be argued that some questions are not problems, but attempts to do even more, but this tag is still useless.

Comment: Agreed. Most questions do describe problems (albeit sometimes in the positive sense of the word), and it would be terribly burdensome to actually expect people to tag all their problem-describing questions with [problem].

Comment: As jrg notes, no question actually uses this tag at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the tag got removed from all the questions.

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS no. tags are only blacklisted if it's really, really, really big and evil. I can't reveal the full details, but there are only 4 blacklists, and half of them are spam site related.

Comment: @jrg OK, got it.