# Can we *please* blacklist the error tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-block-request

The tag has reappeared two more times *again*.

---

The [error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/error) has reappeared after at lease 2 purges.  Can we please blacklist this tag?

[image]

*Reasons for this have been discussed several times already:*

[The 'error' tag should be blacklisted](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5888/the-error-tag-should-be-blacklisted)

[Why do we have an “error” tag?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2363/why-do-we-have-an-error-tag)

[Request: Burnination and Blacklisting of [error] tag](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2541/request-burnination-and-blacklisting-of-error-tag).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No tags ending in error or errors are allowed now. Those that existed have been removed.

Answer (score 4):

*The [error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/error) tag has gotten to the point where mods should probably ask SE employees to blacklist it.*

<sup>That's how tag blacklisting is achieved.</sup>

This tag seems to come back slowly--a couple posts here and there. But I can't deny it keeps coming back. Furthermore, it doesn't seem like discussion of it on meta has kept it from returning. It might even be coming back more often than in the past (though if so, I suspect that's just because we're policing it better now--the more times we get rid of it, the more times it's *possible* for it to come back).

I've been [skeptical](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/5889/22949) of blacklisting this, partly for [reasons jrg articulates here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/2542/22949) and in [this comment](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3441/tag-elimination-problem#comment5029_3442) (where he says, "tags are only blacklisted if it's really, really, really big and evil. I can't reveal the full details, but there are only 4 blacklists, and half of them are spam site related.")

However, as this keeps coming back, and shows no sign that it will stop coming back, it seems that **the applicable standard is to blacklist it**. Unless things have changed since August 2011, the guideline in [this post by Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103145/185080) probably still applies:

> Ok this tag is now blacklisted; any tag we destroy *that comes back from the dead*, needs to be blacklisted.

So, I recommend an AU moderator at least talk to Stack Exchange about this. (Unless there is a newer, higher bar for blacklisting that I'm not aware of.)

Comment: Don't the SE employees patrol the [meta-tag:tag-blacklist-request] tag?  Anyway, that's what I wanted.

Comment: @Seth I'm not sure. We haven't gotten any SE response on the previous, popular requests to blacklist [tag:error].

Comment: (edit done)  Actually, SE employees *have* responded.  Many times.  E.g.: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3706/please-blacklist-the-help-tag and http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1008/please-can-we-destroy-the-subjective-tag and http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/985/blacklist-the-linux-tag and http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/973/blacklist-the-ubuntu-desktop-tag

Comment: @Seth Right, but not to any of the previous, popular requests to blacklist *the [tag:error] tag*. (By the way, I'm not sure the [tag:subjective] tag was actually *blacklisted*.)

Comment: No, they didn't reply to *that*.  Maybe because it wasn't tagged [meta-tag:tag-blacklist-request]?  Oh, I see the newest one was.