# [warning]: questionable tag detected

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

We have 57 posts tagged [warning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/warning). Should they be retagged to remove it?

[warning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/warning) is not as bad as [the banned *error* tag](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6054/can-we-please-blacklist-the-error-tag). [error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/error) roughly meant "Something happened!"  There are just a few common meanings of "warning." **They are enormously broad meanings, though.** I don't think we should have this tag.

Most questions tagged [warning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/warning) use it to describe warning messages. It's not very useful to view or subscribe to questions involving any kind of warning message whatsoever. It's very unlikely anybody could be an expert on warnings *in general* and somewhat unlikely anyone would be interested in them as a general topic. Warnings happen for numerous reasons--more than errors, perhaps, in that warnings signify both conditions that may (later) stop something from working right and those that don't. I really don't see any benefit to this tag.

Is it okay if I -- and anyone else interested in doing so -- edit all the posts tagged [warning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/warning) to remove the tag, add other tags if appropriate, and otherwise do whatever edits seem helpful? Or is there is a reason to keep [warning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/warning) after all?

---

Update: As of now, the [warning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/warning) tag has been removed from all the questions that had it. We'll see if it comes back from the dead--but for now, mission accomplished. **Thanks to everyone who helped out!** (I removed it from a few posts, but the great majority of edits were done by others.)

Comment: I am interested in helping to destroy this tag. (I think [warning] means "something happened!" while [error] means "**something happened!!**")

Comment: It's probably a mark of how un[tag:stable] something is.

Comment: oh no, let's delete that one too

Comment: To avoid discrimination, after removing `error` and `warning` you should also remove `fatal`, `info`, and `debug`. :)

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Currently nothing is tagged [tag:fatal]. The [tag:info] tag is about the `info` command, but some questions are wrongly tagged with it and we should remove it from those. [tag:debug] is about debugging, which is *not* most of what we do here, so it's not too broad. Maybe we don't want it but I'd ask on meta to see what people think. If [tag:debug] is mostly used for general troubleshooting then it should go. If not, we can just remove it from the questions that use it in that general way, but keep it on questions about debugging for the purpose of reporting or fixing bugs.

Comment: I apologize. I though [the reference](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Logging_Levels_and_how_to_use_them.aspx) was obvious and I hoped the tongue-in-cheek tone was underlined by the smiley. I guess the joke didn't come up very well.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto :) Sorry, I was distracted by an urge to fix more tagging problems. The reference very likely was obvious. (Though those specific levels, with those specific names, are not universal. So maybe not.)

Comment: No worries, we all appreciate **a lot** what you guys are doing to clean up the tags on this site. Keep up the great work!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would agree that the [warning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/warning) is pointless and while I don't follow specific tags personally I don't see [warning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/warning) as being useful to anyone. I support the idea of eliminating [warning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/warning) entirely and have managed to edit a few but ran out of time.